# PHPUnit and Selenium and getting value from elements issue

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit

So I'm starting out with **PHPUnit** and **Selenium 2**

```
public function testHasALoginForm()
{
    $this->url('/login');

    $username = $this->byName('username');
    $password = $this->byName('password');

    $this->assertEquals('', $username->value());
    $this->assertEquals('', $password->value());
}
```

This only happens when I call the `value()` method from the element and I end up getting:

```
1) test\view\LoginTest::testHasALoginForm
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: GET /session/fdcf0669-1d42-4a35-8e7a-29dec4a0f1e4/element/0/value
Build info: version: '2.42.1', revision: '68b415a', time: '2014-05-29 16:16:49'
System info: host: 'Something.local', ip: '192.168.1.108', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.3', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ->value() method has been removed in selenium v2.42.0. The currently recommended solution is to use `$element->attribute('value')`

@see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=953007b48e83f90450f3e41b11ec31e2928f1605

Comment: Yes, this solved it for me. I found this very hard to diagnose - even stepping through the code and seeing a 500 error coming back from the server via curl didn't shed any light. So frustrating when old code stops working! thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i'm getting exactly the same error with roughly the same code. I am using the same version of selenium as you are.
However I did not get this error when using the 2.39.0 version.
Hence it seems to be either a regression or a deprecated use.